# Azure Functions: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. Already using static HttpClient

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

My function invocations keep failing with the error message `An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`. According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#static-clients) to mitigate this problem I am to use static Http Clients, which I am already doing, but still the error keeps occurring.

However, I do have 4 of those static clients, which I guess is more than strictly 1. But still I would have thought to fare better with 4 static ones than with multiple (non-static) instances.

I would like to really have only 1 client but I do not know how to make it work. There is one function app which as the below helper class defined in it. In Addition there are 3 services which have been extracted to separate class libraries (because they are used in different projects also) I include in my function app and use via DI. The function app and all of the 3 libs include the below helper class.

```cs
public static class Http 
{
    private static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string url, Dictionary<string, string>? headers = null)
    {
        var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
        if (headers != null) req._addRequestHeaders(headers);
        var response = await _client.SendAsync(req);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return response;
    }
}
```

The services in the libs use HTTP to do their own stuff. How would I be able to have the app and all of the libs it references to use the same static http client?

Or do you think the multiple static http classes are not the cause of the problem? There is no such error when running the function app locally in vs code (i.e outside of Azure).

Cheers

Comment: the facts you encountered unexpected resets have various reason, one thing is to have retry to handle, have you consider on Polly httpClientFactory

Answer (score 0):

> Or do you think the multiple static http classes are not the cause of the problem?

This. The error code you're seeing is [`WSAECONNRESET` (10054)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2):

> Connection reset by peer.
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. This normally results if the peer application on the remote host is suddenly stopped, the host is rebooted, the host or remote network interface is disabled, or the remote host uses a hard close (see setsockopt for more information on the SO_LINGER option on the remote socket). This error may also result if a connection was broken due to keep-alive activity detecting a failure while one or more operations are in progress. Operations that were in progress fail with WSAENETRESET. Subsequent operations fail with WSAECONNRESET.

The fact that you're seeing an exception for this indicates it's an *unexpected* reset (there are other times when `WSAECONNRESET` is normal, and `HttpClient` handles those for you).

There's a lot of possible reasons for unexpected resets. If it's *always* happening, it could be a security (TLS) setting mismatch, or a malformed request. If it's *sometimes* happening, it could just be another service restarting/crashing at just the wrong time. Which happens in the cloud, and your service should retry.

> There is no such error when running the function app locally in vs code (i.e outside of Azure).

The next thing I'd try is to [turn the logging up to 11](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-asp-net-core-logging).